# Time efficient recursion for Magical Number

Tags: java, recursion

I was solving the **Magical Number Problem** where the number at nth position is the sum of the previous 3 numbers, minus 1. For example: 0 1 1 1 2 3 5 9 16.... and so on.

I solved it in 2 ways.

**Code 1)** Using Recursion

```
int magicNumber(int n){
    int f = 0;
    if (n == 1)
        return 0;
    else if (n > 1 && n <= 4)
        return 1;
    else
        f = (magicNumber(n-1) + magicNumber(n-2) + magicNumber(n-3)) - 1;
    return f;
}
```

**Code 2)** Using Array

```
void magicNumber(int n){
    long arr[] = new long[100];
    int i=1;
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if(i==1)
            arr[i] = 0;
        else if(i>1&&i<=4)
            arr[i] = 1;
        else
            arr[i] = (arr[i-1] + arr[i-2] + arr[i-3]) - 1;
    }
    System.out.println("Result is : "+arr[n]);
}
```

**Code 1** works fine when I provide a small integer number to the program, but it hangs with the input of bigger integer numbers and **Code 2** runs fine without any problem.

So I need your suggestions, how can I improve the performance of the recursion program **Code 1**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can speed up your recursion like this:

```
int magicNumber2(int n, int a, int b, int c){
  if (n <= 1) return a;
  return magicNumber2(n - 1, b, c, a + b + c - 1);
}

int magicNumber(int n) {
  magicNumber2(n, 0, 1, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're experiencing delay for higher numbers because each recursive call ends up in 3 more recursive calls. Hence the time rises exponentially. Try this approach:

Maintain a lookup table. Here I have an array `magic_num[100]` with all it's elements initialized to `-1`.

```
int magicNumber(int n){ 
    if(n == 1)
    {   
        magic_num[n] = 0;
        return 0;
    }   
    else if(n>1 && n<=4)
    {   
        magic_num[n] = 1;
        return 1;
    }   
    else if(magic_num[n] == -1) 
    {
        magic_num[n] = magicNumber(n-1) + magicNumber(n-2) + magicNumber(n-3) - 1;
        return magic_num[n];
    }
    else
        return magic_num[n]; 
}
```